# Rails nested form display fields in index page along with parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**index.html.haml**

I have a customer details form which has a nested form named 'goods address'. I want to display all the customer details in index page.

```html
 %tbody
        - @customer_details.each do |customer|
          %tr
            %td= customer.customer_name
            %td= customer.customer_id
            %td= customer.address
            %td= customer.state
            %td= customer.email
```

**nested form**

```html
= fields_for customer_detail do |f|
  = f.fields_for :goods_address do |t|
    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = t.label :delivery_address,"Goods to be delivered at same address mention above?", class: "col-sm-6 control-label text-right"
        = t.check_box :delivery_address, autofocus: true, class: "toggle-two customer-goods col-sm-6", :value => "On"
    %br
    %div{id: 'customer_goods'}
      .main-center-pan.main-login-pan
        .fieldset
          .row
            .col-sm-12
            = t.label :name,"Name", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
            = t.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
            = t.label :contact_no,"Contact number", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
            = t.text_field :contact_no, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        %br
```

**parent form**

```html
= nested_form_for(@customer_detail) do |f|
      - all_views_side_error_messages!(@customer_detail)
      .form-alignment
        .fieldset
          .row
            .col-sm-12
            = f.label :customer_name,"Organisation/Customer Name", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
            = f.text_field :customer_name, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
            = f.label :residential_type,"Residential Type", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
            = f.check_box :residential_type, autofocus: true, "data-width" => "200", class: "toggle-two-resident select-resident col-sm-3"
        %br
```

The problem is I dont know how to define the nested form's fields in the index.can someone plz help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understood properly, you want to show child's attribute on index action of parent controller, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the `child-attributes(goods_address)` with `parent(customer_details)`, just loop the association of the parent object.

```
%tbody
- @customer_details.each do |customer|
  %tr
    %td= customer.customer_name
    %td= customer.customer_id
    %td= customer.address
    %td= customer.state
    %td= customer.email
    - if customer.goods_address.present?
        %td= customer.try(:goods_address).try(:delivery_address)
        %td= customer.try(:goods_address).try(:name)
        %td= customer.try(:goods_address).try(:contact_no)
```

Comment: still i get the same error. but this time not for nilClass. undefined method `each' for #<GoodsAddress:0x0000000440bab0> getting error like this.